# I have a big problem with my js express routers

Tags: node.js, express

I have a big problem with my roads. My route that points to the root of my site is server.use ("/", routerGlobal) in the app.js file. This links to the index.html.twig web page located in the views folder. In the index file there are two links, one must point to   located in a signup subfolder itself in the views folder, the other to   also located in a login subfolder in the views folder. But neither seems to work I get a 404 page not found error message.

But when I take the code from the signup.router and login.router file to place it in the routerGlobal file, my different pages are displayed normally.

I put the code of my three routers at the bottom of the message.

Thanks again for your help and I have attached screenshots of my code.

**HERE THE APP CODE**

```
 const express = require("express");
    const server = express();
    const morgan = require("morgan");
    const routerGlobal = require("./routers/global.router");
    const loginRouter = require("./routers/login.router");
    const signupRouter = require("./routers/singup.router");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    
    
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/biblio2", {useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true});
    
    server.use(express.static("public"));
    server.use(morgan("dev"));
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    
    server.use("/", routerGlobal);
    server.use("/signup", signupRouter);
    server.use("/login", routerGlobal);
```

**HERE GLOBAL ROUTER CODE**

```
 const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const twig = require("twig");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    
    router.get("/login", (req, res)=>{
        res.render("login/login.html.twig")
    })
    
    
    router.use((req , res,next) => {
        const error = new Error("Page non trouvée");
        error.status= 404;
        next(error);
    })
    
    router.use((error, req ,res) => {
        res.status(error.status || 500);
        res.end(error.message);
    })
    
    module.exports = router;

**HERE SIGNUP ROUTER**

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const twig = require("twig");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");



router.get("/signup", (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log("Il y a un problème!!!!");
    res.render("Signup/signup.html.twig");
});



module.exports = router;

**HERE LOGIN ROUTER**




const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const twig = require("twig");


router.get("/login", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login/app_login.html.twig")
})

module.exports = router;

****HERE HTML CODE****



 {% extends "base.html.twig" %}
    
    {% block stylesheet %} 
    <link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    {% endblock %}
    {% block title %}Acceuil Weebank{% endblock %}
    
    
    {% block content %}
    
    <a href="/">Acceuil</a>
    <a href="/signup">Ouvrir un compte</a>  
    <a href="/login">Connexion</a>
            
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I do not understand what exact problem you're asking for help with.  What specific route has what specific problem?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My problem is with the signup and login route not showing up when I use the signup.router and login.router. But when I move the code into global.router everything shows up

Comment: Is this `singup.router` misspelled in this line: `const signupRouter = require("./routers/singup.router");`.  You have `signup.router` when other places you spell it as `signup`.

Comment: thank you for the answer.

No, it's not misspelled elsewhere. And the strange thing is the code works when I put it in global.router. I am a bit lost.